# How to "url-loader" images in Express + Webpack + Handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, webpack

Hello I am using Express with Handlebars as view engine and would like to know how to embed images in my templates and make them "visible" to Webpacks' `url-loader`.

Maybe one possible solution would be to use `handlebars-loader` but I would prefer not to use it.

**What I would like to achieve** is to use the Handlebars' equivalent of Jades'

```
img(src=require("./my/image.png"))
```

but without the use of `handlebars-loader`. Thanks

Comment: I have similar question but I would like simply to use file-loader on images so they would get transfered from src files to the deployment folder. I had no luck with `handlebars-loader` which ignored images but it turned out `handlebars-templates-loader` (another handlebars loader package) did the trick, so my guess is it depends on the template loader. Still I wish I knew if there was a different way regardless of the template package.

Comment: Just found out this issue in `handlebars-loader`: https://github.com/pcardune/handlebars-loader/issues/37. Seems like in general either the loader takes care of it in its own way or you might be lucky that chaining the template loader with something like html-loader is possible: one parses the images the other does the templating, but as the linked issue thread demonstrates chaining loaders is not so straightforward.